# Merging an object to a list of objects

Tags: javascript

Hi all I’m trying to merge a object into each object inside an array something like this

Object to be inserted/merged:

```
Object1 : {‘name’:””}
```

The array of objects into which above needs to be merged

```
Array : [{‘dob’ : 22011991}, {‘class’ : 8208}]
```

And, the expected output:

```
[ {‘name’:””,’dob’ : 2201191},  {‘name’:””,‘class’ : 8208}]
```

Comment: what have you tried? show us your code

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to understand what you want to do.

Comment: Please try this: `const updatedArray = origArray.map(obj => ({ ...obj, name: '' }));`

Answer (score 0):

```
const object1 = {name: ''};
const arr = [{ dob: 22011991 }, { class: 8208 }]
const merged = arr.map(item => ({ ...item, ...object1 }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something similar, but if you just want to push one key from object1.

```js
const object1 = {name: ''};
const arr = [{ dob: 22011991 }, { class: 8208}]

const merged = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  const currentObjInArr = arr[i];
  merged.push({...currentObjInArr, ...object1})
};

console.log('merged: ', merged);
```

Comment: Kindly ensure that the code snippet works. The above answer has been edited to fix issues and now it generates the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution by using `.map` and `...` spread.

```js
console.log(
  [{dob : 22011991}, {class : 8208}]
  .map(obj => ({
    ...obj,
    ...{ name : ""}
  }))
);
```